# I was given a cluster that uses PBS but where do I start MySQL?

Tags: mysql, cluster

I am in a fix. I requested my support people to provide me with some extra CPU and storage resources and they gave me a cluster to work with along with a front-end. The problem is, they are asking me not to start any job on the front-end and that I need to submit a "job" to the backend. Now, I finished compiling mysql on the front-end but how am I supposed to run the server and client?

Do I submit them as jobs or am I missing something here?

Comment: @Mark: This carries on from Stackoverflow actually. I am trying to index a table having 3 billion records and 71 million strings for some data processing. In my current system, it was either taking too long even after using MySQL partitions or my system was running out of space.. So I thought I'd just ask for some extra resources temporarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your support folks solved the wrong problem.  PBS is not going to help you distribute the load on your MySQL server, whever you locate it.  Now if you could use some of those cluster nodes to build a [MySQL Cluster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL_Cluster)...

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I think you are right. I opened a support ticket with them again :( But in the mean time, can you kindly suggest how I can make use of the cluster to do this? Do I download the MySQL Cluster package and compile it on the cluster node?

Comment: Thank you for the pointers. I don't have root on the clusters. I will open another ticket with them. Thank you for your help.